# tastypie get_list filter queryset

Tags: python, django, tastypie

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
  class Meta(object):
    queryset = models.Projects.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'projects'
    list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
    always_return_data = True
    default_format = 'application/json'
    user = auth.ValidateUser()

  def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
    user_projects = super(ProjectResource, self).get_list(request, **kwargs)
    result = json.dumps(user_projects.content)
    return http.HttpResponse(result,
                             content_type='application/json', status=200)
```

This is my tastypie resource. If I found a user from auth.ValidateUser() I need to reply only the associate project from projects table. If not I want to display a error dict saying no project is assigned. I'm not a able to add a filter to get_list.
I'm able to do with get_object_list but if I wanted to reply a custom response like error dict ({'error': 'No user mapped.'}) it is throwing error `AttributeError: "'dict' object has no attribute 'filter'"`

Any help is much appreciated here.

Comment: What's `user = auth.ValidateUser()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the filtering in `get_object_list`, then in `get_list` if the queryset is empty return your dict.

Alternatively, in `get_object_list` you can do:

```
from tastypie.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
response = http.HttpResponse(json.dumps({'error': 'No user mapped.'}),
                         content_type='application/json', status=400)
raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=response)
```